# Wishing to equip my pet Archon

Tags: nethack

I'm a Level 5 dwarves Valkyrie, at Dlvl 6 now, in the Gnomish Mines. I was lucky enough to get a wand of wishing from a jackal, ask for a blessed figurine of an Archon and make it my pet.

There is no denying that an Archon is a good pet(I've just seen it killing a shopkeeper in 2 turns!), so I guess nobody wants to lost it, or make it hostile. My wand of wishing has only been used once, which means I can have another [4-6](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Wand_of_wishing) wishes.

My questions: What should I wish for to make this pet fiercer and/or safer? Maybe a ring of polymorph control? Also, any tips for me? Perhaps wishing for a pet is stupid, but I've never seen such a powerful creature before, and it's my pet now!

Bonus question: How to check the equipments my pet currently has?

Answer (score 3):

Checking your pet is done in four ways. 1&2) : (shift colon=look) and/or #chat will tell you monster, tame/friendly or monster #chat will give you a hunger approx. if a pet that can communicate--see wiki). 3 a stethoscope will give some idea of things like invisible, confused, blind, etc 4 A wand of probing will tell you much more like equipment and carried items, Cancelled, etc. -- see wiki). I also am playing a Valk, and have a pet archon,  I tried giving him a +2pair of gauntlets of power and +3Mjolnir, but for now he prefers a +4 leather glove and +7 RPLS. I will update if he changes preferences based on enchantment.  (I really would like to see him throw that thing.)

Archons are naturally magic resistant and just get stronger in that respect. They can equip (as can many other monsters -- see wiki), you just need to know what they can use (ex; archons can armor up except  for body armor, but they won't exchange unless there's a definite gain).Weapons are similar but there are quirks ( see my question about Djinnis and Demonbane).
Mainly, with an archon, ki-rin, or any other inediate ( they don't eat) monster, NEVER LEAVE THEM ON ANOTHER LEVEL, they will forget you fast.Archons are awesome until they turn on you. So, it's best to have a magic whistle, and use it often with these monsters ( I had a V Lord that I gave all my extras to, and fell down a trap door,.  It took me 8 ticks on the time counter to get back up, and it went peaceful.   Good thing I was chaotic... I never retamed it, but I wouldn't have wanted it to turn feral.  Scrolls/spells of taming combined with some way of draining level (multiple times, re magic resistant) are needed for retaming.

If/when you get to Ludios, the castle, or find a barracks/throneroom, let it wander a while,. It will find the good stuff even if you don't.  Be patient when giving a +2 to replace +1, they don't always like change.
As far as wishes go, consider yourself luccccccky, and do what Kevin says ( see the wiki for specifics) but don't waste another wish just to super it up(it's probably stronger than you as it is).  Let it fight/win and level up, then maybe when it becomes resistant, get a blessed ring of conflict and use that and the whistle to get you out of jams like an arch-lich summoning nasties...

After that, an enchanted shield of reflection (if it doesn't already have), an amulet of lifesaving is a must ( they don't leave corpses to reanimate), and heavily enchanted armor (fixed enchanted non-metal --boots--elven if you have the scrolls to max with-- gloves dexterity maybe, but not really a boon,  and helms HoBr if poss).  Try to use a whip to steal its weapon, identify and enchant to return, or give it your 2nd best artifact/highly enchanted fixed Longsword).    may Tyr be with you........

Answer (score 3):

> Also, any tips for me?

Most of this information comes from [the wiki](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Wish#Early_wands_of_wishing):

Before doing anything else, the standard first wish from an early wand of wishing (i.e. not the guaranteed one you find in the Castle) is "two blessed scrolls of charging."  You may not get two, but you will get at least one.  This ensures you will have an opportunity to recharge the wand (unless you are profoundly unlucky and wrest the last charge from it before learning it's empty - consider burning an identify on the wand to avoid this) and should be prioritized over everything else, unless you already have a means of (blessed) charging at your disposal.

The *next* standard wish is "blessed +2 silver/gray dragon scale mail."  If you have magic resistance, ask for silver.  If you have reflection, ask for gray.  If you already have both, decide what you want your ascension kit to look like and pick one.  If you have not completed Sokoban, remember that you have a 50% probability of getting an amulet of reflection that way.  For monks, this wish is not applicable because they cannot (reasonably) benefit from armor (at low levels).

The third standard wish is a "blessed greased bag of holding."  This is enormously useful if you do not already have a bag of holding.  If you have not yet completed Sokoban, do that first since you have a 50% chance of acquiring a bag of holding that way.  The wiki also recommends [speed boots](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Speed_boots) at this point, but I consider them a lower priority item until the ascension run.  They make a reasonable escape item, but the E-word is nearly as effective even with the nerfs in 3.6.0.

It is somewhat common to wish for [artifact weapons](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Artifact_weapon) next if you do not already have one (e.g. lawful players can easily acquire Excalibur) and are not one of the roles that has a reasonable guaranteed sacrifice gift (e.g. wizards get Magicbane).  This should be done as early as possible because once two artifacts exist in the game, you are no longer guaranteed to get them via wishes (and it may be wasteful to try).  When wishing for weapons or armor of any kind, always prefix it with "blessed fixed +2" to ensure you get as many bonuses as possible.  Inherently fooproof materials like dragon scale don't need "fixed," but it is harmless to include.

At this point, you should fill out your [ascension kit](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Ascension_kit) with whatever items you judge will be most difficult to acquire.  If you've not yet reached the Castle, you may want to wait until that point.  There is a guaranteed wand of wishing in the castle, so you will have a lot of flexibility at that point, and you are more likely to have most of an ascension kit by then.

Do not wish for anything while [unlucky](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Luck), if at all possible.  It will mess up your wish in a variety of ingenious ways and generally ruin everything.